# Performing element-wise standard deviation in R with two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, negative-number

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to get the standard deviation per element from two separate matrices. However, I am quite the beginner at R and I can't seem to figue out how to do this. Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish with a small sample of my data (first three rows)

I have two matrices with coordinates (df143 and df143_2, or matrices A and B as you will)

A:

```
[1,]  21.729504  -55.66055  -37.26477
[2,]  39.445610  -67.67449  -32.19464
[3,]  57.604027  -54.16734  -28.48679
```

B:

```
[1,]  21.706865  -55.50722  -37.57840
[2,]  39.553314  -67.68414  -31.95995
[3,]  57.286247  -54.13008  -28.44446
```

I am looking for an matrix output that shows the standard deviation per element of the two combined matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can do base `R`:

```
matrix(mapply(function(x,y) sd(c(x,y)),A, B), ncol=ncol(A))
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.01600819 0.10842068 0.22176990
#[2,] 0.07615823 0.00682358 0.16595089
#[3,] 0.22470439 0.02634680 0.02993183
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking to do:

```
library(abind)

a <- c(21.729504, -55.66055, -37.26477, 39.445610, -67.67449, -32.19464, 57.604027, -54.16734, -28.48679)
a <- matrix(a, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

b <- c(21.706865, -55.50722, -37.57840, 39.553314, -67.68414, -31.95995, 57.286247, -54.13008, -28.44446)
b <- matrix(b, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

m <- abind(a, b, along=3)

apply(m, 1:2, sd)
##            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
## [1,] 0.01600819 0.10842068 0.22176990
## [2,] 0.07615823 0.00682358 0.16595089
## [3,] 0.22470439 0.02634680 0.02993183
```

Comment: Thank you, although I already have the two matrices available in my workspace as functions. Sorry if that was unclear. However, this will definitely be usefull to me for future reference!